# Multiple Character separator for awk command

Tags: linux, awk

I have the data as below:

```
p_id^|^data1^|^data2^|^data3
```

I need to get the 2nd field only

```
data1
```

Tried multiple tricks with `awk` command, but unable to find it out. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the separator contains more than one character and all of them are special (both `^` and `|` are regular expression operators), you need to escape them.  On the command line, you would do this with

```
awk -F '\\^\\|\\^' '{ print $2 }' file
```

You need the double backslashes to escape the backslashes themselves too (for a different reason).

Comment: Thank you ! Great Help !